# Java 8 Streams: Iterate Over a List Inside a Map

Tags: java-stream, iteration

I am facing a problem in iterating over a List inside an Object which is embedded inside another map.
My objective is to iterate over this list and produce a map<String,String>, I want to achieve this using streams and lamdas.

```
public class ModelBO {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String version;
    private Map<String, FolderBO> folderValues = null; 
}

public class FolderBO {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    private List<ElementBO> elements = new ArrayList<ElementBO>();
}

public class ElementBO {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

I seen above i need to create a map with map<id,name> from the elementBo by iterating over elementList which is inside the folderBo. The folderBo itself is inside the map of ModelBo.

I have written the following code.

```
  Map<String,String> elementMap = 
    UniModelBO.getInstance().getFolderValues().entrySet().stream()
       .filter(entrySet -> entrySet.getKey()!="relations")
       .map(entrySet -> entrySet.getValue().getElements()::stream)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(ElementBO::getName, ElementBO::getId));
```

UniModelBO is utility class that creates a singleton object for ModelBo.

Comment: What is `UniModelBO.getInstance().getFolderValues()`

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a set of example data and an expected result. Also, why not try and use conventional loops to achieve what you're going for? Far easier to translate into streams, if it's even necessary.

Comment: Its a utility singleton class that creats ModelBo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, just use `flatMap` to convert the nested `List` stream into a single stream. And I will also recommended to use the `equals` method for string comparison:

```
Map<String, String> elementMap =
        UniModelBO.getInstance().getFolderValues().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entrySet -> !entrySet.getKey().equals("relations"))
                .flatMap(entrySet -> entrySet.getValue().getElements().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(ElementBO::getName, ElementBO::getId));
```